# Help debugging php code

Tags: php, debugging, wordpress, plugins

I'm hacking into a wordpress plugin. Since I'm inside a plugin that posts tweets, I use something like echo or print. I've identified one line that causes the problem, but not sure what exactly it is, since I can't print or echo.

```
$tagarray = wp_get_post_tags( $post_id); //returns an array
$tags = "tag:";
if (count($tagarray) > 0){
    foreach ( $tagarray as $tag ){
        //$tags .= "mytag ";  // This line  works when quotes are removed.
        //$tags = strval($tag);  //This doesn't.
    }
}
```

I've tried various manipulations of $tag, like casting etc, but nothing works. Any ideas on how to debug? My last resort would be to publish print values to a file. Any other ideas?

Comment: This is a plugin running on server side at the backend. So the var_dump etc doesn't get published on my browser.

Comment: You can still do print_r or others, you just have to do it differently.  fopen a text file and output the results to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incomplete.

Yes, `wp_get_post_tags()` returns a list of tags, but each tag in that list is itself an object containing the following:

- term_id
- name
- slug
- term_group
- term_taxonomy_id
- taxonomy
- description
- parent
- count

So you need to do this instead:

```
$tagarray = wp_get_post_tags( $post_id ); //returns an array
$tags = "tag:";
if (count($tagarray) > 0){
    foreach ( $tagarray as $tag ){
        $tags .= strval( $tag->name );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In you're loop use :

```
var_dump($tag);
die();
```

You should be able to see exactly what type of is $tag and what content . the loop will stop imediatly after the first value .

Answer (score 1):

I find [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) (addon for [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/)/Firefox) very useful for debugging php, you can send messages, arrays, variables to the firebug console before headers are sent.

Answer (score 1):

for debugging php I use [PhpED](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phped.htm)
you can set breakpoints in the code without any modifications, 
so there is no chance that you'll leave some echos in the code.

Answer (score 0):

for debugging use var_dump or print_r

Answer (score 0):

that doesn't work because you missed to concatation operator (.) in the second line

```
$tagarray = wp_get_post_tags( $post_id); //returns an array
$tags = "tag:";
if (count($tagarray) > 0){
    foreach ( $tagarray as $tag ){
        //$tags .= "mytag ";  // This line  works when quotes are removed.
        $tags .= strval($tag);  //This will work Changed = to .=
    }
}
```

And if are looking for debugging the code FirePHP is a good tool, also you could use any PHP IDE with builtin debugging like eclipse or something.

And in wordpress you can use [WP-Debug Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-debug/)

Comment: I had intentionally deleted the "." to simplify my code. No joy. :(

Comment: Does WP-Debug version work with recent version of WP. It was last updated in 2007.

Answer (score 0):

To debug, since it won't output any sort of debugging info to the browser, do this, or something similar:

```
$logger = fopen('debug.log','a');
fwrite($logger,"Begin Debug - " . time() . "\n------------\n");
$tagarray = wp_get_post_tags( $post_id); //returns an array
$tags = "tag:";
if (count($tagarray) > 0){
    foreach ( $tagarray as $tag ){
        //$tags .= "mytag ";  // This line  works when quotes are removed.
        //$tags = strval($tag);  //This doesn't.
        fwrite($logger,$tag . "\n");
    }
}
fwrite($logger,$tags . "\n");
fwrite($logger,print_r($tagarray) . "\n");
fwrite($logger,"----------\n End Debug \n\n");
fclose($logger);
```